# can't get the http post parametes in rest service

Tags: apache, cxf

I want to create a rest service, which should retrieve all the available HTTP POST parameters in the request, note that the parameters are dynamic hence I can't use FormParam.

I made the rest service to consume form url encoded and got access to HttpServletRequest object using org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext.getHttpServletRequest(), but I can't find any parameters in the request.

Any idea how to retrieve all the http post parameters available in the httpservletrequest object in rest server ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay I just had to have MultivaluedMap as the argument for my rest service, this map will have all the http post parameters in it.